# How to save data in rails with no form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, save

I am new to rails and I am just learning the basics.
This is my code on saving data:

***app/controllers/employee_controller.rb***

```
 class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      render json: @employees = Employee.all
    end

    def show
      render json: @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @employee = Employee.new
    end

    def create
       @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)

      @employee.save
      redirect_to @employee
    end

    private
       def employee_params
         params.require(:employee).permit(:fname, :mname, :lname, :contactno, :address, :username, :password)
       end
 end
```

***app/views/employees/new.html.erb***

```
<%= form_for @employee do |f| %>
<p>
  <label>First Name</label><br>
  <%= f.text_field :fname %>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Middle Name</label><br>
  <%= f.text_field :mname %>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Last Name</label><br>
  <%= f.text_field :lname %>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Contact No.</label><br>
  <%= f.text_field :contactno %>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Address</label><br>
  <%= f.text_area :address %>
</p>
<br>
<p>
  <label>Username</label><br>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
</p>
<p>
  <label>Password</label><br>
  <%= f.text_field :password %>
</p>
<br>

<p>
  <%= f.submit %>
</p>
```

But, my goal is to save right away without the html form. (NO INPUT) Like when I visit a certain URL and the values are automatically saved in the database. 
For a start, I would like to assign a constant value in every field just to see how it works.

Example,

- fname='sample name'
- mname='sampleMidName'
- lname='sampleLastName'
  and *etc...*

How can I assign those values right away after a certain URL/site is visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller try something like:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  def custom
    @employee = Employee.create(fname: "sample name")
  end
end
```

and define proper route in *config/routes.rb*:

```
get "/custom" => "employees#custom"
```

When you enter proper url in your browser, like:

```
localhost:3000/custom
```

The `Employee` should be saved.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You start by adding a method to your controller

```
def update_fname
    # get the parameters
    fname = params[:fname]

    # get the employee ID
    id = params[:id]

    # find the employee
    @employee = Employee.find(id)

    # update the employee
    employee.update_attributes(fname: fname)

    redirect_to @employee
end
```

Then, in your route, you add:

```
resources :employees do 
    get 'update_fname'
end
```

And you call the route, who should be `http://localhost:3000/employees/{:id}/update_fname?fname={your_fname}`

Comment: what if i'm going to add new record? how should it go in order to get a link with parameter?

Comment: You just add a new function in you controller such as `create_employee`.